# Naming convention for simbol of clojure.core/atom, like !foo in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I found a naming `!video` on Reagent docs.

```clj
(let [!video (clojure.core/atom nil)]
...)
```

https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent/blob/master/doc/FAQ/UsingRefs.md

I liked this rule of prefixing `!` to signify mutation, but I couldn't find any information suggesting that it's a widely recognized convention within the Clojure community. Do you have any information on whether such a convention exists? Alternatively, are there any other naming conventions for representing `atom` variables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I liked this rule of prefixing ! to signify mutation

This does not signify a "mutation", it signifies a [reference type](https://clojure.org/reference/atoms). As in something that holds a value, which may change over time.

As for your question, you can probably ask 10 people and get 10 different answers. This is extremely subjective. In the end does it matter whether this is "widely recognized" anywhere? If it makes sense to **you, or your team**, then by all means use it. Conventions are only useful if you think they are useful. As long as you are consistent, it really doesn't matter what you do. IMHO.

This particular `!` prefix I personally don't like because I find `@!video` visually "noisy". Yet, I agree that it is absolutely useful to "mark" names, to signify what they represent. I tend to use a `-ref` suffix instead, so `video-ref` instead of `!video`. I have never seen anyone else do that, but I still like it.

Comment: Thank you. I agree that overlapping marks are a little noisy.

Comment: Note that `@` is the [deref](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/deref) reader literal. `@thing` is identical to `(deref thing)`, so technically not the same as what I called "mark" above. Doesn't change that I don't like the `@!` combo though. Another common "mark" are so called "earmuffs" for dynamic `*binding*` vars.

Comment: `-ref` is a nice idea, we use `*` at the end to indicate that you need to `deref` the symbol to get the value.

Comment: I would tend not to use a special symbol, but rather a suffix `-atom` or `-atm` if you for special cases. This is especially useful for storing a numeric value in different units or formats, eg `height-in`, `height-m`, `height-cm`, `height-mm`.  Also works for `seconds-int8`, `seconds-int4`, `seconds-dbl`, `seconds-float`, etc.

Comment: Regarding the original use case of atoms, you are really quite fail-safe, as the first time you forget to use either `@video` or `(deref video)`, even the simplest unit-test will fail and alert you to the problem.

Comment: The problem with that is that often you'll have `(let [video @video] ...)` which shadows away the ref. I frequently overlook this and then wonder why a later `swap!` doesn't work. Better not to have that problem in the first place by picking good names, than relying on tests catching it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no recommendation in the style guide.

https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide?tab=readme-ov-file#Atoms

I follow the Tonsky recommendation:

https://tonsky.me/blog/readable-clojure/#use--as-prefix-for-references